# Error: The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a single document via a Stream Provider for each user and have the below user model

```
class User {
  String userID;
  String userName;

  User({ required this.userID, required this.userName });

  factory User.fromMap(Map data) {
    return User(
      userName: data['username'] ?? '',
      userID: data['userID'] ?? '',
    );
  }

}
```

In my DB file, I have the following StreamBuilder.

```
class Database{
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<User> user(String userID){
    return _firestore.collection('users').doc(userID).snapshots().map((snap) => User.fromMap(snap.data()));
  }


}
```

I'm getting the following error: "The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'."

Any idea how I can resolve?

Comment: Please don't post plain error messages in the question title. You are a SO member for more than four years, you should know.

Comment: Look at the clutter on the right, how many questions with the same title. Don't be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler clearly said that the map data type you declare is `<String, dynamic>?` and the data you are getting is of `map type <dynamic, dynamic>`. as you only mentioned user class I believe the error occurs in it.

In that case you can try 2 things

**Solution 1**

return `snap.data() as  Map<String, dynamic>`

```dart
 Stream<User> user(String userID){
    return _firestore.collection('users').doc(userID).snapshots().map((snap) => User.fromMap(snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
```

**Solution 2**

```dart
class User {
  dynamic userID;
  dynamic userName;

  User({ required this.userID, required this.userName });

  factory User.fromMap(Map data) {
    return User(
      userName: data['username'] ?? '',
      userID: data['userID'] ?? '',
    );
  }

}
```